# Containing DIV to "cover" contained elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I have HTML like so:

```
<div id="cover" on-tap="_overlayTapped" class$="{{status}}">
  <form method="POST" action="/some/action">
    <input required id="name" name="name" label="Your name"></input>
    <input required id="surname" name="surname" label="Your name"></input>
    <button type="submit">Click!</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I would like to add Javascript or styles so that the div `#cover` will:

1) Blur its contents. For example, while the form is loading (via AJAX) some default values, I want the contained stuff to be "blurred" (I guess with `#container`'s opacity) but also I don't want people to be able to click on fields.

2) Turn `#cover` into something "modal", meaning that clicking on it will effectively wait for a click to attempt a reload of the data (if the call failed)

Is doing this effectively impossible with a "containing" div? I realise that when I click on a field, the event will be on the field itself, and it will then bubble up to the container... Am I getting it the wrong way around?

Comment: Both requirements should be possible. Can you include `css`, `javascript` tried at Question?

Comment: It's actually a very complex Polymer element... This is the simplified version!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure about what you want to make but I made this for you, please check if this is what you want. Click on the button to open the modal, it box will appear and other contents will be blured.

Here is the code:

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("blurit").style.filter = "blur(4px)";
    document.getElementById("blurit").style.WebkitFilter = "blur(4px)";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("blurit").style.filter = "blur(0)";
    document.getElementById("blurit").style.WebkitFilter = "blur(0)";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("blurit").style.filter = "blur(0)";
    document.getElementById("blurit").style.WebkitFilter = "blur(0)";
    }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="blurit">
<p>Test it</p>
<img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/909/flowers-garden-colorful-colourful.jpg" alt="Pineapple" width="500" height="300"><br><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Try it</button>
</div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```